# neural network: speedup sim initialization

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I profiled the `sim(net,input)` function (part of the neural network toolbox) and noticed it spends a relatively lot of time in the initialization part calling `net=obj2struct(net)` every time `sim` is called. Is there any way (beside writing my own ad-hoc sim function) to pass as parameter the already converted struct-type net in order to avoid wasting time converting every time? (convert once, run multiple times)

It would be very nice for NN relatively small (like the one I'm using), whose conversion takes more time than the simulation itself.

Comment: well, turns out you can call nnsim.y, but you have to manually manage input data format. For small networks (in my case a single layer feed forward net) execution time is reduced to a tenth.